Installing Standard Windows on an SSD via USB (not Windows To Go)
I'm prepping my old laptop for eBay, and I removed the old drive inside with all my data so it can't possibly be recovered by someone else. Of course, this means I need to replace the storage with something, and I happen to have a spare SATA SSD around I got for free, never wrote to it.
The only problem is that my laptop does not have any SATA cable or hardware inside, and my attempt to install a basic SATA cable (with the same number of pins as the motherboard) resulted in what I think was a short (PC turned off immediately after putting the cable in), so I think I might have borked the internal SATA connection.
I have a SATA-to-USB cable, though. I want to use this as a stopgap until I can fully diagnose what happened and potentially put the drive inside the laptop. However, standard Windows doesn't install over USB.
Is there any way to trick the Windows 10 installer into allowing an installation over USB to this SSD?

Just sell the laptop without a storage device.  However, if you attempted to install a SATA drive into a laptop, without a SATA port, there is no telling what damage you might have done.

It was the cable that caused the sudden power off. I didn't physically jam the drive into the device! The motherboard had a header for SATA.

You installed a SATA cable while the system was turned on?  Why? Your laptop does not support hot swapping SATA drives. The only way to install to this drive would be to use Windows To Go. A buyer wouldn't want that long term.

I installed the cable on the drive and then installed the whole thing in the laptop. I then turned it on to see if it would detect the drive (had a Linux USB installed as well) and the machine would not turn on for more than a few seconds. I then tested some things and singled the problem down to the cable's attachment to the header.

That sucks if so. I was hoping for a workaround but I guess I can just sell it empty.
